# Solution for the URL Alias and question marks issue with Webform

Tags: 7, uri

I am developing a site in Drupal 7. I am using webform for creating a "contact us" form. After submitting the from successfully, the page is redirected to a confirmation page where the url is http://www.somesite.com/node/11/done?sid=3. I want this particular url as http://www.somesite.com/thankyou.

I tried to set the url alias for **node/11/done?sid=%** as **thankyou**. But unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Any suggestions about a solution for this?

Comment: The default submission URL is dynamic (hence the `sid=`), but there's an option to send your submission to a custom URL, does this work for you ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried with custom url. But only the **node/11/done** portion of the url changes to **thankyou** . Now the url will be _thankyou?sid=3_. I need the whole url to be replaced by _thankyou_.

Comment: i have the same issue, and i use the url alias to solve my problem but the query string '?sid=..' always displayed, i think we can remove it with jquery

Answer (score 1):

By default, [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) will redirect you to an internal URL with the submission parameter `sid`. The only way to prevent this parameter to being displayed is to redirect the user to an external URL.

What you can do is set up a [bit.ly](http://bitly.com) short URL that targets your *thankyou* page, therefore webform will think it's an external URL, won't add the submission parameter and the user will land on your http://www.somesite.com/thankyou page.

Comment: Thanks @tostinni.. But I got a solution for it using another method. I used form_alter of the webform and created a custom function for submit in which I changed  the url of submission page.